# How can I use readline inside of a ncurses application?

Tags: c++, readline, ncurses

I'd provide some input features inside of the `ncurses` application I'm currently working on. I want to show the `readline` prompt by pressing some key, maybe `ESC` and then letting the user edit the line.

The problem is, I don't know how to display it and how to redirect control to `readline`.

Comment: If you're using curses, curses expects to handle all terminal input and output. Full stop. The only thing you can do is call `endwin()`, to disengage curses from controlling the terminal, use `readline()`, then `refresh()` to reengage curses afterwards.

Comment: it is sad. I wanted to handle all the "drawing" part by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [example](https://github.com/ulfalizer/readline-and-ncurses/blob/master/rlncurses.c) application. The code is clear enough, it displays the input from embedded readline.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks.